# Confusion about homography matrix

Tags: python, numpy, computer-vision, linear-algebra, homography

I'm trying to get a homography matrix that describes the transformation from one image to another. I tried doing this by using an eigendecomposition and taking the smallest eigenvector. Apparently, I have to reshape it into a 3x3 matrix, but the numpy linalg function returns an eigenvalue of shape (9,9). (trying to compute it from 4 points)

A is a 8x9 matrix. pts1 and pts2 are arrays of 4 points in the source image and the target image respectively.

Code starts from symmetry matrix for homography calculation (size 8x9)

```
A_t = A.transpose()
sym_mat = np.dot(A_t,A)

eig_val,eig_vec = np.linalg.eig(sym_mat)

#sort according to value
idx = np.argsort(eig_val)
eig_val = eig_val[idx]
eig_vec = eig_vec[:,idx]
# Return the eigenvector corresponding to the smallest eigenvalue, reshaped
# as a 3x3 matrix.
H = np.reshape(smallest,(3,3))
```

`

Comment: Why don't you use the SVD solution to find the homography.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/494238/how-to-compute-homography-matrix-h-from-corresponding-points-2d-2d-planar-homog/4841217#4841217) for a concrete example for how to compute the homography matrix `A` (9x9) from a set of 4 `src` and the corresponding `dst` points.

Continuing with the same example, but dropping the last row of the matrix `A`, so that the dimension now becomes 8x9, the homography matrix can be estimated with the above code, as shown below

```
A = A[:-1,:]
print(A.shape)
# (8, 9)

sym_mat = np.dot(A.T,A)
eig_val, eig_vec = np.linalg.eig(sym_mat)

# sort eigenvalues and choose the index corresponding to the smallest eigenvalue 
idx = np.argsort(eig_val)[0] # here is where the above code had mistake
eig_val = eig_val[idx]
eig_vec = eig_vec[:,idx]
# Return the eigenvector corresponding to the smallest eigenvalue, reshaped as a 3x3 matrix.
H = np.reshape(eig_vec,(3,3))
H = H / H[2,2] # normalize, assuming the last entry of the matrix to be 1
print(H)
# [[ 1.68470998e+00 -9.45348887e-02  1.45839239e+01]
#  [ 5.00688641e-02 -9.70746853e-01  2.42751631e+02]
#  [ 2.64367645e-03  2.77831031e-04  1.00000000e+00]]
```

Verify that the estimated homography matrix matches with the one computed with `opencv-python`:

```
import cv2
h, _ = cv2.findHomography(src, dst)
print(h)
# [[ 1.68471000e+00 -9.45348782e-02  1.45839218e+01]
#  [ 5.00688662e-02 -9.70746856e-01  2.42751631e+02]
#  [ 2.64367648e-03  2.77831077e-04  1.00000000e+00]]
np.allclose(H, h)
# True
```